# CSimpleIniA - method of wrapper class doesn't read config file value

Tags: c++

I wrapped [CSimpleIniA](http://code.jellycan.com/simpleini/) in a Config class to manage configuration options in a 'config.ini' file.

In the example I provide, `sample_size` is read in the `Config` constructor.
When `readSampleSize()` is called, the value of the configuration file is returned.

By contrast, `readInitialPos()` should (what I expected) be able to read the `config.ini` and return the value of `inital_pos`.  Instead, it returns the default value, the third argument `70000`.

I don't understand why this second method is not working.

config.hpp

```
class Config {

private:
    unsigned long int sample_size;  
public:
    unsigned long int readInitialPos ();

    unsigned long int readSampleSize ();

    CSimpleIniA ini;

    Config ();
};
```

config.cpp

```
#include "../include/config.hpp"

Config::Config () 
{
    CSimpleIniA ini;
    int error_nr = ini.LoadFile("config/config.ini");
    if ( error_nr ) {
        cout << "Error " << error_nr << " opening config.ini file." << endl;
        exit(3);
    }
    sample_size = ini.GetLongValue("Rock", "sample_size", 50);
}

unsigned long int Config::readInitialPos ()
{
    return ini.GetLongValue("Rock", "initial_pos", 70000);
}   

unsigned long int Config::readSampleSize ()
{
    return sample_size;
}
```

caller, rock.cpp

```
void Rock::readConfig ()
{
    Config config;

    initial_pos = config.readInitialPos ();

    sample_size = config.readSampleSize ();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Config::Config () 
{
    CSimpleIniA ini;                                     // <== here!
    int error_nr = ini.LoadFile("config/config.ini");
    // etc...
}
```

That's a bug.  Your local `ini` variable hides the ini member of the class.  So your readInitialPos() method uses an CSimpleIniA object for which you never called LoadFile().

Simply delete it to fix the bug.

Fwiw, avoid using .ini files, they are horribly expensive.  Reading a value takes about 50 milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that.  Regarding your last paragraph, what do you propose instead of an .ini file?